# Only one base currency is displaying in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, system-config

I have a magento store that is pre made by some one. In that in admin panel system configuration in curreny setup base currency, I have found only one currency "Australian dollar".How can i enable or install other currencies By default in magento store it displays all currencies..

Thank You

Comment: You can also check the allowed currencies and if they have a conversion rate configured.

Answer (score 4):

What I think has happened here is that the list of installed currencies has been edited. You can see this list under `Advanced->System->Currency->Installed Currencies`. What you can do here is define which currencies are installed on your system, if there is only one item set here then there will only be one allowed currency in the rest of your shop.

If you simply want to have the default currencies then you can delete the entries in the table `core_config_data` where the path is like `system/currency/installed`